# Access to Button click handler not executing in a webpack project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, frontend

I have a very simple setup to understand the webpack basics.
Below is my project structure

[image]

While running the project and upon clicking on the buttons in the **index.html** page, the handlers are not getting executed instead log errors in the console.

Please find the project [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nadh7p?file=src%2Findex.js&terminal=)

This may be a very silly question, but I could not understand this behavior. Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the functions unless you export them when you use webpack.

`index.js`

```
export function click_blue() { ... }
export function click_red() { ... }
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    library: 'lib',   // add this!
  },
  mode: 'development'
};
```

`index.html`

```
...
<button onclick="lib.click_red()">Red</button>
...
```

Check [webpack output.library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to add the library as you suggested and also looked into the webpack documentation, However, I still can not achieve the output. not sure if I am missing anything. I am sharing the link [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-nadh7p?file=dist%2Findex.html&terminal=) while trying to access the `lib` it returns `undefined`

Comment: Remove `type="module"` attribute in `script`, and rebuild and refresh it. Try removing a cache too.